# Implement a Notification System

Tags: jquery, notifications

I have an element `.msg_counter`. It is hidden, if the text inside it is 0.

The whole thing should be a notification for incoming messages, which shows the number of unread messages, so periodically I want to check for changes and if the element is changed and not 0, show it on the page and play a sound.

This is, what i have got so far:

```
jQuery('.msg_counter').each(function(i,el)
{
    var msg_counter = jQuery(el);
    if(msg_counter.text() == "0")
        jQuery(this).hide();
    else
        jQuery(this).show();
});
```

I need help with the "refresh and sound"-part.

Just in case, that there is an easier approach for it via the function, `ultimatemember_message_count()` is the function, which gives the output (number).

Comment: Do you have a single `.msg_counter` field? Or you have so many?

Comment: i have at maximum 2 of them, and if, both would contain the same value.

Answer (score 1):

use like this to play a sound on show

```
jQuery('.msg_counter').each(function(i,el)
{
    var msg_counter = jQuery(el);
    if(msg_counter.text() == "0"){
        jQuery(this).hide();
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.soundjay.com/path_to_mpe_file.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
        });
    }else{
        jQuery(this).show();
}
});
```